# Reload a jsf datatable using jquery

Tags: jsf, primefaces

my data table

```
<h:form>
   <h:dataTable value="#{testController.items}" var="item" border="0">
       <h:column>
           <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
       </h:column>           
   </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

i'm using a modal to hold my form, the modal contains this commandbutton

```
<p:commandButton styleclass="btn btn-primary" action="#{testController.create}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
```

handleComplete function:

```
function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
    if(args.validationFailed) {  
        alert("failed");
    }else{
        $('#test-modal').modal('hide');

          // Do something here to reload the datatable to add the newly created item

    }
}
```

im using jsf 2 and i also imported primefaces

Comment: Is `commandButton` also in this `form` together with `dataTable`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) to generate a JavaScript function which invokes a JSF command action.

```
<h:form>
   <h:dataTable id="table" value="#{testController.items}" var="item" border="0">
       <h:column>
           <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
       </h:column>           
   </h:dataTable>
   <p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" action="#{testController.update}" update="table" />
</h:form>
```

This can be invoked as follows:

```
function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
    if (args.validationFailed) {  
        alert("failed");
    } else {
        $('#test-modal').modal('hide');
        updateTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried what you suggested but it seems the action is not invoked, i tried debugging and added a sysout on the method but it seems it is not invoking it.